# Warning: simplexml_load_file() [function.simplexml-load-file]: I/O warning : failed to load external entity

Tags: php

> Warning: simplexml_load_file() [function.simplexml-load-file]: I/O
>   warning : failed to load external entity
>   "USD_en_productdata/USD_en_productdata.xml"

the code

```
$src=simplexml_load_file("USD_en_productdata/USD_en_productdata.xml");

foreach($src->ProductItem as $i){
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? Does the file exist? Try with an absolute (not relative) file path.

Comment: the xml file in folder so i make USD_en_productdata/USD_en_productdata.xml

Comment: The error message really couldnt be any more helpful ... its saying it cannot load the file you specified ... check path / spelling / permissions etc

Comment: add as a first file: `var_dump(is_file("USD_en_productdata/USD_en_productdata.xml"));` the result will be probably `false`. I advise to use absolute paths. Like `dirname(__FILE__)."/USD_en_productdata/USD_en_productdata.xml"`

Answer (score 7):

Try to pass full directory path if you are trying to load xmls held at your server

```
simplexml_load_file($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/uproYourFoldet/USD_en_productdat/USD_en_productdata.xml')
```

or if you want to access xml by http protocol you will need to set allow_url_fopen ON in php.ini or

```
ini_set('allow_url_fopen ','ON');
```

in your code. or you can also do this if you are using php version <5

```
$temp = file_get_contents($url);
 $XmlObj = simplexml_load_string($temp);
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like your path might not be correct.

In my experience, it's best to surround simplexml_load_file and subsequent functions with if statements with file_exists(...) as the condition.

So in your case:

```
if(file_exists($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/yourPathToFile/...')) {
simplexml_load_file($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/urltoYourFolder/USD_en_productdat/USD_en_productdata.xml')
}
```

EDIT: spelling