# simplexml_load_file() not working when trying to load intranet RSS

Tags: php, rss, simplexml

I'm trying to load a wordpress RSS feed using simplexml_load_file and failing.

I have a PHP script that lives on our internal web server (intranet) and a wordpress blog that lives on intranet/newsletter. I'm trying to pull the RSS feed from the blog into our intranet using the following code ad failing:

```
$rss = simplexml_load_file('intranet/newsletter/feed/');
```

This is the error I get:

> Warning: simplexml_load_file(): I/O warning : failed to load external
>   entity "intranet/newsletter/feed/" in /var/www/html/intranet/test.php
>   on line 69

I've tried using

```
$rss = simplexml_load_file('http://intranet/newsletter/feed/');
```

with no success.

From a browser intranet/newsletter/feed/ works fine.

Comment: Is `intranet` representing something else?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9771666/warning-simplexml-load-file-function-simplexml-load-file-i-o-warning-fai  Verify `ini_set('allow_url_fopen ','ON');` ?

Comment: php runs on the same machine that have browser pointing to intranet?

Comment: Yes, ini_set('allow_url_fopen ','ON'); is present.

Comment: @dev-null-dweller both the newsletter rss feed and the intranet are on the same internal web server.

Comment: can you try using server ip address (like `http://1.2.3.4/newsletter/feed/`) instead of `intranet` to see if it works?

Comment: @dev-null-dweller great, thanks that works. Create this as an answer and I'll mark as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comment:

> can you try using server ip address (like
>   `http://1.2.3.4/newsletter/feed/`) instead of intranet to see if it
>   works?

For some reason php is unable to map intranet into IP. Do you have proper entry for intranet in `/etc/hosts` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use file_get_contents function

```
 $xml = simplexml_load_string(file_get_contents('http://intranet/newsletter/feed/'));
```

Comment: Tried your suggestion, which gives me this:

Warning: file_get_contents(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known in /var/www/html/intranet/test.php on line 693

Comment: as suggested from dev-null-dweller, try to use IP instead of the domain name:    simplexml_load_string(file_get_contents('http://10.10.1.1/newsletter/feed/'))